# tmpfile() function doesn't work

Tags: php, xampp, fopen, temporary-files, fclose

I wrote a code shown below.

---

```
<?php

$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, "writing to tempfile");
fseek($temp, 0);
echo fread($temp, 1024);
fclose($temp);

?>
```

---

But this code gave me this error below on a browser.

---

> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php on line 4
>   Warning: fseek() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php on line 5
>   Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php on line 6
>   Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php on line 7

---

If I use `fopen()` instead of `tmpfile()`, it works well.
I don't know why it doesn't work.

If you know something about this, could you teach me, please?

*By the way, I use XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

check what

```
sys_get_temp_dir()
```

returns and make sure that folder is writable.

Comment: It returns /var/folders/vd/n1v7wzns59d3m3dwzvgr57p00000gn/T

Comment: and the folder is writable.